Nautilus and Thunar can't connect to remote VPN NFS
I am using a Wireguard VPN connection to maintain someone else's network.
Locally, I am on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.
Remotely, I am logging in on the subnet using 192.168.1.0/24 too, via the VPN's 192.168.9.0/24 subnet.
After creating this connection, I added a route using Ubuntu's network manager:
Address       Netmask         Gateway       Metric
192.168.1.0   255.255.255.0   192.168.9.1    

This works fine. If I enter 192.168.1.1 in Firefox, I get to the remote router's administration page. Other HTTP servers on the remote network's subnet also work properly in my web browser.
However, in Nautilus and Thunar, if I try to mount the NFS location nfs://192.168.1.5:/mnt, I get the error:

Unable to access location
Mount point does not exist

Note: I installed nfs-common. Also, using ssh://user@192.168.1.5 in Nautilus does work.
What can I do to resolve this error?

Doh - turns out I forgot to install nfs-kernel-server on the remote host.
Install by issuing:
sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server

